# How to split list into separate values?

Tags: racket

I want to use the [bitwise-and](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._bitwise-and%29%29) function to get the biggest bitwise result for combinations of elements inside a list. The problem is bitwise-and function requires (n ...) integers but [combinations](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._combinations%29%29) function return list. How can I pass the list to the bitwise-and function?

This is my code:

```
 (for-each (lambda (arg)
     (printf "Got ~a\n" (bitwise-and arg)))
     (combinations '(1 2 3 4 5))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29):

```
(for-each (lambda (arg)
            (printf "Got ~a\n" (apply bitwise-and arg)))
          (combinations '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```